# adding new first and last column to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need to add the first and last column to a numpy array, the column that i have to add have to be equals as the previous first one and previous last one, so for example:

```
1 5 4 
2 5 3
==>
1 1 5 4 4
2 2 5 3 3
```

but i have to do that with an image that has three values:

```
(rows,cols,depth) = image.shape
```

Comment: See np.concatenate and np.hstack as well as broadcasting and views. It is certainly a good idea to read the official tutorial first: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) with `mode='edge'`:

```
out = np.pad(a, ((0,0), (1,1)), mode='edge')
```

output:

```
array([[1, 1, 5, 4, 4],
       [2, 2, 5, 3, 3]])
```

Explanation:

```
((0,0),  # pad rows: (before, after)
 (1,1))  # pad cols: (before, after)
```

You can easily increase the number of dimensions if needed by adding more tuples.